# Must multiple forces be expressed as a differential equation?

Tags: forces, differential-equations

This may be a stupidly obvious question, but can multiple forces  (such as acceleration due to gravity and air resistance acting on a falling object) be expressed algebraicly or must it be written in the form of a differential equation? Since I don't know much about differential equations I have struggled to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You only need differential equations when you are trying to find movements, and the forces change over time (or position).

At any given time, the forces can be written as a normal equation. Differential  equations come into play when you look at their changing over time.